# Exomedia demo play the same song when back press and select the another song

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am new in android and I have downloaded the exomedia demo app. I have 5 songs in the list view, 4 songs from server and one from sdcard.

when I start playing first time by clicking the list item, player start playing the song, when I press back button and play another song the same previous song get played.

Please please Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AudioPlayerActivity you need to update the startPlayback() method to be

```
private void startPlayback(boolean forceStart) {
    //If we are changing audio files, or we haven't played before then start the playback
    if (forceStart || playlistManager.getCurrentIndex() != selectedIndex) {
        playlistManager.setCurrentIndex(selectedIndex);
        playlistManager.play(0, false);
    }
}
```